# Why is my Ethereum block number 0 in geth, even though the sync is nearly complete?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

```
> w3.eth.syncing
AttributeDict({
  'currentBlock': 5787386,
  'highestBlock': 5787491,
  'knownStates': 138355583,
  'pulledStates': 138341120,
  'startingBlock': 5787335,
})

> w3.eth.blockNumber
0
```

I had done full sync but blocknumber is always 0.

Answer (score 5):

Peter, the lead geth developer, posted a thorough response to this question here: [Block number is always zero with fast syncmode](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16411#issuecomment-377176640). To add slightly more color to carver's answer, while you may have received the most recent block headers (`eth.currentBlock`), your node probably still has a lot of work remaining to download the entire state tree. To quote Peter:

> Many people falsely assume that because they have the blocks, they are
>   in sync. Unfortunately this is not the case, since no transaction was
>   executed, so we do not have any account state available (ie. balances,
>   nonces, smart contract code and data). These need to be downloaded
>   separately and cross checked with the latest blocks. This phase is
>   called the state trie download and it actually runs concurrently with
>   the block downloads; alas it take a lot longer nowadays than
>   downloading the blocks

Comment: This information is important and answers the problem for me. I was using the default fast sync mode and my node is simply never fully sync, or only for a brief time, because of the time it takes for the state processing. Need to get my latest block with eth_syncing method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same situation as [Why is my ether balance 0 in geth, even though the sync is nearly complete?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete) but with a slightly different "symptom".

To quote the important bit:

> `geth --fast` has an interesting effect: geth cannot provide any information about accounts or contracts until the sync is fully complete.
>
> Try querying the balance again after eth.syncing returns false.

Note that in addition to accounts and contracts, you also cannot retrieve any information about blocks until the sync is complete.

When your sync is fully complete, `syncing` will return false, like:

```
> w3.eth.syncing
False
```

Comment: My sync is fully complete according to your definition but the `blockNumber` is still 0 even after restarting `geth`. Wat do?

Comment: After waiting for roughly 5 minutes without touching it the `w3.eth.syncing` doesn't return `False` anymore and the sync is currently in progress again... Interesting :)

Comment: Ah, I suppose it's possible that `syncing` will return false if your internet connection drops or something like that. So yeah, best to check both syncing and block number.